# Where can I find the source code of "GFileInfo" functions like "g_file_info_get_content_type"?

Tags: gnome, source

I want to read the source code of a GFileInfo function:
g_file_info_get_content_type ( GFileInfo *info );

Could somebody tell me where to find the source code file? I search the glibc code by didn't found the functions.

These function are introduced in this link: http://library.gnome.org/devel//gio/2.26/GFileInfo.html

Comment: Note that this is [Glib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib), not [glibc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glibc). Every character counts!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [the file](http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/gio/gfileinfo.c) you are looking for. Note that the page you linked is generated from it.

It's actually part of [GLib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib) (GTK+ Library) which is part of the GNOME project, but is used by a host of other software projects. You might wanna get [a git checkout](http://www.gtk.org/download.html) for the sake of convenience.